# Adjust bar/column chart symbology and legend in ArcMap 10.7

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology

I'm generating a map using the bar/column chart symbology in ArcMap (see first image). When choosing this, ArcMap automatically sets the size and scale of the bars and creates a number for the legend. In my case, this number is 6km³. If I have just one layer, this would be no problem.
However, I have multiple layers with different extents of their values. Thus, ArcMap plots the bar chart of each layer in a different size (in the attempt to maximize the visibility). But this way there is no comparability between layers.

I can set my class ranges etc. with nearly all other symbologies, is there no possibility to do this here?

I've tried to use the `Import` button to import the extent of another layer, but apparently `This symbology option is not supported for importing` (see second figure).

My question is more or less the same as [Bar/Column Symbology Table Of Contents](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-enterprise-questions/bar-column-symbology-table-of-contents/td-p/4600) at the Esri Community.

Is there a way to change the resolution of a bar chart or to apply the same scale for multiple layers?

[image]

This is my error:
[image]